# javascript: object Object instead of value from set =(

Tags: javascript

So, I'm trying to have same data plotted based on a drop down filter, but I haven't gotten past the storing the data to the variable passing to the plotting function. my alert gives `object Object`, but shouldn't it be `totalValue` (for this example)?

the html

```
   <select id="performance_chart_filter">
  <option value="totalValue">Total by Value</option>
  <option value="openValue">Open by Value</option>
  <option value="declinedValue">Declined by Value</option>
  <option value="acceptedValue">Accepted by Value</option>
</select>
```

the javascript

```
$j("#performance_chart_filter").change(function(){
    plotWithChoice();
});



function plotWithChoice() {
   var d = {
        "totalValue": {
            label: "Total",
            clickable: true,
            hoverable: true,
            data: <%= @total %>
        }
.
.
.
};

    var filter = $j("#performance_chart_filter");
    var data = [d[filter.val()]];
alert(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `filter.val()` would most likely be the string `"totalValue"`.

`d[filter.val()]` (or `d["totalValue"]`) would be the value of the property `totalValue` of the object `d`, which is an object thus the output `Object object` of the `alert`, because that's the default string representation of a generic object like this.

And `[d[filter.val()]]` is a Array with one element namely the object mentioned above.

To debug this, I'd suggest you use a Debugger (such as Firebug), because that can display objects in a readable form.

Or use the `.toSource()` method:

```
alert(data.toSource());
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the members of the d object are similar to the one shown, and d is in scope, then `alert(data)` will always will show "object Object".

If `filter.val()` is "totalValue", then data will be the Object:

```
{
  label: "Total",
  clickable: true,
  hoverable: true,
  data: <%= @total %>
}
```

This doesn't have an explicit `toString` method, so the default `toString` will be used.

Try `alert(data.label)`, hopefully this will show "Total".